# Why can't I get Dolby Digital sound from Android TV box linked to Sony AVR?

Tags: audio, android-tv

I have just bought my 1st Android TV box (it's a Chinese CS918 rk3188 model) and since it has SPDIF/optical out I hooked that to my Sony AVR's optical input and set the device manager in the Android TV box to enable "passthrough". I played a video which has 5.1 Dolby Digital sound using MX Player, but alas, even though all of the notification Dolby Digital display lit up on my Sony AVR no sound came out of the speakers!

I got sound straight away when I switched to PCM sound but I am very disappointed as I prefer Dolby Digital. What can I do to get DD sound or does my specific model of Android TV box not support DD sound

Here is a screen shot of my sound devices manager settings:

[image: sound devices manager]